# After creating revocation certificate for OpenPGP key unable to locate it

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I created an OpenPGP key. It is an RSA key pair. I created revocation certificate:

```
gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke $GPGKE
```

But I am unable to locate the file `revoke.asc`. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

GnuPG's `--output` option accepts both relative and absolute paths. If you just pass a file name, it will store the file in the current working directory. If you don't remember it's location any more, search your hard disk:

- Using the GUI method of your choice
- Try the `locate` command first, which uses an index, but might be out of date:

  ```
  locate revoke.asc
  ```
- Search the whole hard disk (which will take some time):

  ```
  find / -name revoke.asc
  ```

If you don't find it (and still have access to the private key): don't worry, just generate a new one.

Comment: If you really want to search through all of `/` you should consider using `sudo` to call it. Besides that your answer is good.

Comment: I'd rather just ignore error message using `find / -name revoke.asc 2>/dev/null`. The revocation certificate shouldn't be in any locations not accessibly by your system user, and there is no reason running `find` with elevated privileges therefor.

Comment: Also fine :) just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type

```
find -name "revoke.asc"
```

It will display you the location of the file